# Tabular SSAS - RLS and ALL dax function

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular, row-level-security

I have a Tabular Analysis Services Model with Row Level Security.
There is a Power BI report when the Tabular model is the source.
If I create a measure in DAX (at the power BI level) with the ALL or ALLExcept function, will RLS be ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Row Level Security is applied prior to any other operation. No DAX function can remove it.

Keep your RLS as simple as possible to avoid performance issues.